# change view after viewDidAppear (Storyboard)

Tags: iphone, view, storyboard

how can I change a View (with code) (switch the View to the View I named in the Code) in the viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated function from a view? 
I use storyboard.

EDIT:

```
View_Info *Info =[[View_Info alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:Info animated:NO];
```

No Error only warning:

"PredentModalViewController animated is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS6

Thanks for help

Comment: have you tried anything so far for that? if yes then write some code and error you getting

Comment: use this

[self presentViewController:Info animated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: Thanks. But one more problem now This Code I tried was with xib files not storyboard. How can I use this with Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this and modify this code as per your requirement and if worked don't forgot to accept this answer and upvote :) thanks.

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MainViewController *mvc = (MainViewController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;    
LoginViewController *lvc = [mvc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[currentVC presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: OK thanks can you help here again: MainView is Named "Launch" and Login is Named "Start"

Comment: in your storyboard there will be a xib for your Start viewController and give it a Identifier "Start" and then use this above code and write this 

    [mvc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Start"];